# Cannot change tintColor of a flipped UIImage image Swift 2 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a code where, depending on whether a condition is true, an image is flipped and its tintColor changed.

```
func incoming(incoming: Bool) {
    let image = UIImage(named: "MessageBubble")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    var shownImage: UIImage
    // Check whether it is an incoming or outgoing message
    if incoming {

        let flippedImage = UIImage(CGImage: image!.CGImage!, scale: image!.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.UpMirrored)
        shownImage = flippedImage.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
        bubbleImageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 200/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)

    } else {

        shownImage = image!
        bubbleImageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)


    }

    bubbleImageView.image = shownImage

}
```

However, this code does not flip the image but it is correctly applying the tintColor. If the ".imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)" function is removed, the image is correctly flipped but the tintColor is not applied. (bubbleImageView is a UIImageView).

The code under else block shows up with the correct tintColor.

How can I get both the image flipped and its color changed?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add color for your images with this method:

```
func coloredImage(image: UIImage, red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) -> UIImage! {

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: image.size)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, image.scale)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    image.drawInRect(rect)


    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, red, green, blue, alpha)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.SourceAtop)

    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return result


}
```

So, in your case, you should do:

```
let processedImage = coloredImage(bubbleImageView, red: 100/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with this code! It seems to be awfully complicated to do something really simple. But why can't "flippedImage" in my original code be treated as its own UIImage and then tinted? I don't get why my code wouldn't work.

Comment: Don't know why not working tintColor. Kind of buggy maybe when used in conjuction with flipping stuff.